# Convert GMSMapView coordinate to iPhone screen point(x,y)

Tags: ios, objective-c, coordinates, gmsmapview

I have tried to covert the marker position latitude-longitude to iPhone screen x and y coordinate, but it gives me negative value sometimes.

MapView is added in main view from storyboard.
self.mapView.frame - It is equal to main view frame
iPhone 8 plus simulator = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 414, height = 736))

Marker position : (latitude = 22.811061859130859, longitude = 70.862533569335938)

```
CGPoint pointInScreen = [self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
```

Returns value -  (x = -38547.58203125, y = 7061.60107421875)
Which is not screen point. My marker is visible on the screen.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to find out the screen x,y coordinate based on the marker latitude-longitude position?

Comment: What is your MapView frame? and how it is added?

Comment: Yes. It is visible. I have added custom marker to marker.iconView. I also call the [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position], but the issue is that sometime only half marker view is visible when it is near to the edges of map view. So I want to check whether the whole marker view is visible and inside the map or not?

Comment: What does `marker.position` print?

Comment: (latitude = 22.811061859130859, longitude = 70.862533569335938)

Comment: It can never be negative if marker is visible. You might be doing something wrong what you are unable to describe here.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the marker position I mean in which function?

Comment: Thanks @TheTiger. Now I am getting the correct result. Just your last question made the things right. Before I called it from a custom function and that time camera is also animated (using animateWithCameraUpdate). Now I am calling it from -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position. And it's worked.

Comment: I helped you now its your time to help me... Check my updated answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to check:

1. `marker` should be visible on map.
2. Cross check your `coordinates`.
3. `[self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position]` function will work after loading the map properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

- Retrieve the bounds of your viewport with [GMSVisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/struct_g_m_s_visible_region) .
- create a [GMSCoordinateBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds)
- Call [containsCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds#a88501beb137edd044e4dde9d1f73a0a5) . It should return true if the marker is within the viewport and false if not.